# Kotlin on converting to generic class

Tags: generics, kotlin

How do you convert the code below to a generic class, so that one can specify type parameter `T` instead of concrete type `User`?

```
class UserService : BaseService {  
    val query = datastore.createQuery(User::class.java)
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

@Ufkoku is correct but I thought a bit more explanation might help.

```
class UserService<T>(val clazz: Class<T>) : BaseService {  
    val query = datastore.createQuery(clazz)
}
```

Note that using Kotlin's [reified generics](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/inline-functions.html#reified-type-parameters) you can also create a convenience construct for the above that allows you to construct one without passing the `Class` instance:

```
class UserService<T>(val clazz: Class<T>) : BaseService { 
    val query = datastore.createQuery(clazz)

    companion object {
        inline fun <reified T> create() = UserService(T::class.java)
    }
}
```

So then you can construct these as either `val s = UserService(String::class.java)` or `val s = UserService.create<String>()`

Answer (score 0):

```
class Service<T>(val type: Class<T>) {

      val query: Object

      init {
          //init query
      }

}
```